# How to match uppercase word character with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I know there is the `[A-Z]` notation.. but I am not sure if `[a-z]` is the same as `\w`.

**I'd like to match `\w`, but only if it's uppercase.**

This should include all the weird characters like `Ę, Ą, Ś, Ć, Ź, Ż, Ś, Ł, Ó, Ń`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `\w` if all you want is to match unicode uppercase letter?

Comment: I want to get the equivalent of `\w`, but uppercase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). For example,

```
'/\p{Lu}/u'
```

Will match any uppercase letter.

Comment: This does not work.. tested here https://eval.in/135620 Am I forgetting something?

Comment: @loostro Sorry I'm not able to open your link.

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out. If I add u (utf mode) it works: `/\p{Lu}/u`. Thanks

Comment: @loostro Ahh, yes. I should have included that. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

`\w` is equivalent of this character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

If you want upper case unicode characters only then use this character class:

```
'/[\p{Lu}\p{N}_]/u'
```

This will match any one of:

1. Upper case unicode letter
2. unicode number
3. Underscore

Comment: I don't actually need the underscore (though it does not hurt either) in my use case, but thanks for explaining what exacly `\w` matches.

Comment: That's the reason I asked a question to you about `\w` but you said you want equivalent of `\w`.

Comment: I wonder, that [posix character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) `[[:upper:]]` also seems to convert to `\p{Lu}` when using u-modifier, didn't expect that: [eval.in](https://eval.in/135661), [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lG8pY1)